# How to solve for $m/n$ given that $(2x^{\frac{1}{6}})^{m} = (2x^{\frac{1}{8}})^{2n}$ for some constant $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, exponentiation

I was solving a problem when I got stuck on a particular step, I don't know how to proceed further.

$$(2x^{\frac{1}{6}})^{m} = (2x^{\frac{1}{8}})^{2n}$$

I want to make the bases equal, so I can compare the exponents (i.e., the ratio of $m$ to $n$). Here $x$ is constant.

I tried but ended up making $x$ terms equal but then 2's exponents (in the base) became different.

Here is [the original question](https://s13.postimg.org/qnq8yfjef/IMG_20171231_193415.jpg):

> If $m$ and $n$ are the smallest positive integers satisfying the
>   relation $$\left(2\, \mathrm{cis} \frac\pi6\right)^m = \left(4\, \mathrm{cis} \frac\pi4\right)^n$$ then find the value of $m+n$.

where $\mathrm{cis}\, \theta \equiv \cos \theta + i \sin\theta$

Comment: Please edit the question to show us just what you tried. Then we may be able to help better.

Comment: What is the variable you need answer of. Is it x,  m or n.

Comment: I want the ratio of m and n, x is a constant ($e^{iπ}$)

Comment: Take logarithm base $2$

Comment: Thanks, but I want the smallest positive integer ratio, how can I get that from log.

Comment: If $x=e^{i\pi}$ then $m/n$ is complex, unless I made a mistake in the arithmetic.

Comment: I get $m=16.635532333438686+9.42477796076938i$, $n=8.317766166719343+6.283185307179586i$, $m/n=1.8183457990784067-0.2404763018435165i$, and $(2x^{\frac{1}{6}})^{m} = (2x^{\frac{1}{8}})^{2n} = -654.5126575339408+328.2493583016928i$

Comment: I have posted the original question link

Comment: @PM2Ring I've also got a complex ratio.

Comment: The answer of m+n is 72

Comment: @drake01 the original problem is more simple than the first one!

Comment: A classic case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For the original problem**

$$\left(2e^{i\frac{\pi}6}\right)^m=\left(4e^{i\frac{\pi}4}\right)^{n}$$

multiply both sides for

$$\left(\frac14e^{-i\frac{\pi}4}\right)^{n}$$

$$\left(2e^{i\frac{\pi}6}\right)^m\left(\frac14e^{-i\frac{\pi}4}\right)^{n}=1$$

$$2^{m-2n}e^{i\left(\frac{m\pi}6-\frac{n\pi}4\right)}=1$$

that is

$$\begin{cases}
m-2n=0\\
\frac{m\pi}6-\frac{n\pi}4=2k\pi
\end{cases}
\implies \frac{n}3-\frac{n}4=2k\implies n=24 \quad m=48 $$

Comment: Thanks, but why did you equate $\frac{mπ}{6} - \frac{nπ}{4}$ to 2kπ instead of 0?

Comment: in general $e^{2k\pi i}=1$ for all k integer, thus you have to use this condition to find all the solutions, for k=0 you obtain the trivial n=m=0

Comment: You are welcome it’s a pleasure for me! Bye

Answer (score 3):

Solving for $x$:
$$(2x^{1/6})^m=(2x^{1/8})^{2n}$$
$$2^mx^{m/6}=2^{2n}x^{2n/8}$$
$$x^{m/6}=2^{2n-m}x^{n/4}$$
$$x^{m/6-n/4}=2^{2n-m}$$
$$x=2^{\frac{2n-m}{m/6-n/4}}$$
$$x=2^{\frac{48n-24m}{4m-6n}}$$
$$x=2^{\frac{24n-12m}{2m-3n}}$$
$$x=2^{\frac{8*3n-6*2m}{2m-3n}}$$
$$x=2^{-\frac{6*2m-8*3n}{2m-3n}}$$
$$x=2^{-\frac{6*2m-6*3n-2*3n}{2m-3n}}$$
$$x=2^{\frac{6n}{2m-3n}-6}$$
$$x=\frac{1}{2^6}2^{\frac{6n}{2m-3n}}$$
The ratio of $m$ and $n$:
$$(2x^{1/6})^m=(2x^{1/8})^{2n}$$
$$m\log(2x^{1/6})=2n\log(2x^{1/8})$$
$$\frac{m}{n}=2\log_{2x^{1/6}}(2x^{1/8})$$
Or:
$$\frac{m}{n}=2\frac{\log(2)+\frac{1}{8}\log(x)}{\log(2)+\frac{1}{6}\log(x)}$$
$$\frac{m}{n}=2\frac{6\log(2)+\frac{6}{8}\log(x)}{6\log(2)+\log(x)}$$
$$\frac{m}{n}=2\frac{6\log(2)+(1-\frac{2}{8})\log(x)}{6\log(2)+\log(x)}$$
$$\frac{m}{n}=2\frac{6\log(2)+\log(x)-\frac{2}{8}\log(x)}{6\log(2)+\log(x)}$$
$$\frac{m}{n}=2\left(1-\frac{\frac{2}{8}\log(x)}{6\log(2)+\log(x)}\right)$$
$$\frac{m}{n}=2-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\log(x)}{6\log(2)+\log(x)}$$
The origial question:
$$2^m \text{cis}(\frac{\pi m}{6})=4^n \text{cis}(\frac{\pi n}{4})$$
$$2^{m-2n}=\text{cis}(\pi (\frac{n}{4}-\frac{m}{6}))$$
The left side is real, so the right side must be real aswell:
$$\sin(\pi (\frac{n}{4}-\frac{m}{6}))=0$$
$$\cos(\pi (\frac{n}{4}-\frac{m}{6}))=2^{m-2n}$$
For the first equation:
$$\pi (\frac{n}{4}-\frac{m}{6})=k \pi$$
$$\frac{n}{4}-\frac{m}{6}=k$$
$$6n-4m=24k$$
For the second, the right side must be 1:
$$m-2n=0$$
So:
$$6n-8n=24k$$
$$-2n=24k$$
$$n=12k$$
$$m=24k$$
But the $\cos$ must be positive, so the smallest possible $k$ value is $2$ (you get $-1$ as the value of the $\cos$ with $k=1$, so the next integer ($k=2$) will give $1$): $n=24$, $m=48$, so $n+m=72$.

Comment: Thanks but I need the ratio of m and n, sorry for editing late.

Comment: @drake01 Yes, I've seen, and edited my answer aswell.

Comment: Thanks, also please tell how can I get smallest positive integer ratio, actually I want to calculate the smallest value of m + n where m and n are smallest positive integers satisfying the above relation (given in question)

Comment: @drake01 Do you want m/n to be the smallest possible value?

Comment: Yes but m and n should be positive integers

Comment: @drake01 and x is a variable now?

Comment: No x is still constant,in fact its value is $e^{iπ}$

Comment: @drake01 hold on a sec.

Comment: @drake01 I think the ratio won't be real.